# Real-life experience of BT Wholesale Ethernet as a bandwidth option

Tags: bandwidth, isp

We are currently moving office, and in the new location we have been offered BT's Wholesale Ethernet as an alternative to a traditional leased line. It seems to be full-duplex, symmetric, uncontended, with a similar SLA to a leased line, but comes in at less than half the cost. 2Mbps is approx £300/month and 10Mbps approx £630/month.

Does anyone have any real-life experience of this product? I understand that it's fairly new and part of BT's 21CN network upgrade. Unfortunately fibre is not available in the building.

Comment: can you make this question more general; right now it's too localized to be of use to most of the world audience

Comment: Not sure how I can make it more generic, but still be useful to me. I am/was after info on this specific bandwidth option, available in the UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably one of these:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_in_the_First_Mile

I've got a bundled version of 2BASE-TL at the office giving us 40Mbit to our Colo and it's so good we didn't even notice when we lost 2.5 of the 8 pairs making up the service until we saw the lights were out on the CPE (naturally the carrier should have called, but Australias carriers are all far too lazy).

Comment: Thanks for the info - after looking into it I think you are right - the service is basically Ethernet over copper.